# Limit of the form $1^{\infty}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to1} (\tan(\pi x/4))^{\tan(\pi x/2)}$$

On direct substitution it becomes of the form 1^infinity in these cases I have been taught to use the standard limit $(1+x)^{1/x}$ as tends to zero it will be equal to $e$ but I am not able to convert the given expression into that form

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following trick:
$$\alpha^\beta = e^{\ln \left( \alpha^\beta \right)} = \color{red}{e}^{\color{blue}{\beta \ln \left( \alpha \right)}}$$
which leaves you with finding the limit of $\color{blue}{\beta \ln \left( \alpha \right)}$, in your case:
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \tan\left( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right) \ln \left( \tan\left( \frac{\pi x}{4} \right) \right)$$
You can transform this into something where you can apply l'Hôpital's rule:
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{ \ln \left( \tan\left( \frac{\pi x}{4} \right) \right)}{\cot\left( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right)}
= \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{ \left( \ln \left( \tan\left( \frac{\pi x}{4} \right) \right) \right)' }{\left( \cot\left( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right)\right)'}
= \cdots$$

Can you take it from there? If not, I can elaborate.

You should find $\color{blue}{-1}$ for this limit, so the answer is $\color{red}{e}^{\color{blue}{-1}} = 1/e.$

Comment: I am not able to understand the application of the trick in my question

Comment: Do you understand that you can always write $x = e^{\ln x}$ (if $x$ is positive)?

Comment: Shouldn't the limit be $e^tan(πx/2)...$

Comment: I left out that part to lighten the notation and just compute the limit inside the exponent; the $e^{\ldots}$ is added at the end again.

Comment: I added some coloring to clarify the parts calculated and the adding of the exponentiation at the end.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this by your fundamental limit

$$\lim_{x\to 1} ({\tan {\frac{\pi x}{4}}})^{tan{(\pi x/2)}}=e^{\lim_{x\to 1} {[(tan{\pi }x/4)}-1]tan(\pi x/2)}$$

because according to your fundamental limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}{(1+x)^{1/x}}=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}{(1+x-1)1/x}}$$
similarly i have subtracted 1 in original limit

then i can write $tan(\pi x/2)$ as $tan(\pi x/4+\pi x/4)$ and then i can use $tan(A+B)$formula using that we will get $$tan(\pi x/2)=\dfrac{2tan(\pi x/4)}{1-tan^2(\pi x/4)}$$,
take this and substitue in the first limit then you can cancel undertermined equations and you will get  $$e^{-1}$$ your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here I use two clever substitutions. The first is $t = \tan (\pi x /4)$. Then, applying the formula
$$\tan (2 \alpha) = \frac{2 \tan \alpha}{1- \tan^2 \alpha}$$
to $\alpha = \frac{\pi x}{4}$, you have to compute
$$\lim_{t \to 1} \ t^{\frac{2t}{1-t^2}}$$
Now, calling $t=1+x$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (1+x)^{-\frac{2(1+x)}{x(x+2)}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \left( (1+x)^{1/x} \right)^{-\frac{2(1+x)}{x+2}} = e^{-\frac{2(1+0)}{0+2}} = e^{-1}$$
so that your original limit is $1/e$.